# Earth Engine terminate ALL Google Drive export tasks

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, export, google-drive, tasks

I have a bunch of tasks leftover from my previous session that I don't need anymore. But since these are waiting in a queue, my new exports are waiting for the previous ones to finish first. Is there a way to terminate all the export tasks in Google Earth Engine?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a simple way using the GUI. For anyone who has the same problem, just use this link and enable the bulk cancel mode.
https://code.earthengine.google.com/tasks

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the Python API you can use [ipygee](https://github.com/fitoprincipe/ipygee).

```
import ee
ee.Initialize()
import ipygee as ui
import tqdm  # you can avoid using this if you want

TM = ui.TaskManager()
TM

# Select the tasks you want to cancel, then:

for task in tqdm.tqdm(TM.selected_tasks()):
    task.cancel()
```

Comment: there is also a button, but avoid using it (I have to fix it).

Comment: FYI, the button is causing errors with importing the library to begin with as of Aug 2023. Getting a `CRITICAL: NameError: name 'instance' is not defined` when trying to import ipygee

Comment: thank you @SeanCarter, yeah, I haven't had much time to maintain that package unfortunately